# How to remove session storage data when the we change the component

Tags: angular, session-storage

I have a x-component, I am storing a value inside  session storage. Now, if I navigate to any other component, I want to remove and go to the other component. I written removal logic in ng destroy but if I use URL patch change then ng-destroy is not executing.

I written removal login in X component ngOnInIt() then , when I refresh x component, session storage is removing , but I dont want this. At the time of refresh , the session storage should remain. Other cases it should be removed.

I dont want to write code in other components to remove , because again other components "MAY" also have same kind of storing the value with the same key.

Answer (score 0):

May be at the time of refresh, you can listen for beforeunload and unload events and You can set some flag in session storage and check the falg exist in ngOnInit. If exist, don't execute remove session storage logic.

You need to listen for window:beforeunload event.

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload') onBeforeUnload() {
   // add your logic
}
```

Comment: For refresh also beforeunload() is executing and if we go to another component also beforeunload executing

Comment: Updated Answer. Please check whether this helps.

Comment: If I refresh the page (same route) then I need to grab the value from session storage and show. But, with this code that is clearing off because, refresh also executing beforeUnload() function. So no use.